# How can I specify a variant for a coffeescript view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When using Rails variants I would use this convention to specify what JS template to use:

```
action.js+variant.erb
```

How can I do the same for a Coffeescript view?

```
action.coffee
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out is `action.js+variant.coffee`.